# Could not find module 'ModuleName' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I have 3 schemes in my app. I am not sure why but when running **on iOS simulator** on one of these schemes(Debug), I get the following error on the import line:

`Could not find module 'ModuleName' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64-apple-ios-simulator, at: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-bgumdcxgpxtntlgtykppxpaxjcji/Index.noindex/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ModuleName.swiftmodule`

Running on any other scheme will succeed, and also **running this scheme will work on real devic**e, but the problem seems to be when running in iOS simulator. Does anyone know why? I have tried to make Build Settings be the same for all schemes, but no success. I have also tried all solution provided in another SO questions but none worked for me.

**Library was installed using SPM**. Before that, it was working fine using Cocoapods. I did not change anything except removing the pod and removing its framework from `Other Linker Flags`(because Xcode was complaining about that).

I was firstly facing this error on Xcode 14.2, and then switched to the Xcode 15. The issue is the same, but Xcode 15 automatically asks me to run the simulator with `Rosetta`, and if I do, it works! However, running Xcode 14.2 with Rosetta was not working.

This was not the case with another library I switched from Cocoapods to SPM, everything worked fine.